# excel combobox keeps activating, and I can't clear it with a macro

Tags: excel, combobox

I have a combobox for dropdown list, that is in another sheet.

The problem is that this combobox keeps activating when you are doing other things, like copying, selecting cells etc.

I managed to solve the problem by limiting combobox to activate only if ActiveSheet = The sheet where the combobox is. But I want to fully limit the combobox from activating unless clicking on [the dropdown arrow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GEx6y.png). By activating I mean that this blue drop down square keeps popping out.

This code is in the sheet code:

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_change()
 Dim sht1 As Worksheet
 Set sht1 = Worksheets("Predloga za račun")

 If ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Name = sht1.Name Then

ComboBox1.ListFillRange = "DropDownList"
Me.ComboBox1.DropDown
Else: Exit Sub
End If
```

Another thing I have trouble with a macro that copies metadata from an invoice and clears the invoice. What I want to do is to clear the search bar of the combobox as well.

At the end I added

```
Sheets.("Sheetname").ComboBox1.clear
```

And here's the problem. When the code execute this line it clears the combobox. Then, for the next line it executes the whole Sheet code and than returns to the same line (Clear combobox), and returns an erros so it can't continue to End Sub

Here's the whole copy metadata code:

```
Sub Meta_Račun_Copy()

    Dim lastrow As Long, zlastrow As Long, erow As Long, frow As Long

    lastrow = Sheets("Predloga za račun").Cells(Rows.Count, 7).End(xlUp).Row

    zlastrow = Sheets("Predloga za račun").Cells(Rows.Count, 14).End(xlUp).Row

    i = 21

    Sheets("Predloga za račun").Range("E3:N60").ExportAsFixedFormat xlTypePDF, Filename:=Sheets("Predloga za račun").Range("P8").Value & "\" & Sheets("Predloga za račun").Range("L13").Value, Openafterpublish:=True

    'Kopira in prilepi datum v Arhiv računov
    Sheets("Predloga za račun").Cells(14, 13).Copy
    frow = Sheets("Arhiv računov").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
    Worksheets("Arhiv računov").Cells(frow, 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

    'Kopira in prilepi št. računa v Arhiv računov
    Sheets("Predloga za račun").Cells(13, 12).Copy
    Worksheets("Arhiv računov").Cells(frow, 2).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

    'Kopira in prilepi stranko v Arhiv računov
    Sheets("Predloga za račun").Cells(13, 6).Copy
    Worksheets("Arhiv računov").Cells(frow, 3).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

    'Kopira in prilepi končni znesek v Arhiv računov
    Sheets("Predloga za račun").Cells(zlastrow, 13).Copy
    Worksheets("Arhiv računov").Cells(frow, 5).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

    Do

    'Kopira in prilepi storitev v Bazo za arhiv
    Sheets("Predloga za račun").Cells(i, 7).Copy
    erow = Sheets("Baza za analizo").Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
    Worksheets("Baza za analizo").Cells(erow, 2).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

    'Kopira in prilepi količino artiklov v Bazo za arhiv
    Sheets("Predloga za račun").Cells(i, 8).Copy
    Worksheets("Baza za analizo").Cells(erow, 4).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

    'Kopira in prilepi znesek artiklov v Bazo za arhiv
    Sheets("Predloga za račun").Cells(i, 13).Copy
    Worksheets("Baza za analizo").Cells(erow, 7).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

    i = i + 1

    'Kopira in prilepi vrsto artikla v Bazo za arhiv
    Sheets("Predloga za račun").Cells(i, 7).Copy
    Worksheets("Baza za analizo").Cells(erow, 3).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

    i = i + 1

    'Kopira in prilepi datum v Bazo za arhiv
    Sheets("Predloga za račun").Cells(14, 13).Copy
    Worksheets("Baza za analizo").Cells(erow, 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

    'Kopira in prilepi stranko v Bazo za arhiv
    Sheets("Predloga za račun").Cells(13, 6).Copy
    Worksheets("Baza za analizo").Cells(erow, 5).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues


    Loop Until i > lastrow



    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    'Samodejno poravna stolpce v Arhivu računov in Bazi za arhiv
    Sheets("Baza za analizo").Columns().AutoFit
    Sheets("Arhiv računov").Columns().AutoFit

    'Počisti vrsticein doda novo prazno
    Sheets("Predloga za račun").Activate
    ActiveSheet.Unprotect
        ActiveSheet.Range("F20").Select
        Selection.End(xlDown).Select
        ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 0).Select
        Range(ActiveCell, "N21").Select
        Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp

        Sheets("Nadzorna plošča").Activate
        Range("G42", "O43").Select
        Selection.Copy
        Sheets("Predloga za račun").Activate
        Range("F20").Select
        Selection.End(xlDown).Select
        Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown
    ActiveSheet.Protect

    Sheets("Predloga za račun").ComboBox1.Clear

    Sheets("Predloga za račun").Activate
    Range("A1").Select

    ThisWorkbook.Save

    End Sub
```

Thanks for the help!

G.

Comment: Change the `ComboBox1_Change()` to `ComboBox1_DropButtonClick()`

Comment: Thanks very much! What an easy solution :) I'm not a programmer, I did some modification to codes I found on internet, so I didn't know this trick :) Thanks a lot!

Comment: Oh! but now it doesn't suggest based on what I'm typing in the search bar. Is there anyway to solve this with suggestion working?

Comment: When you are in the editor for your ComboBox, you have a dropdown menu at the top right of your screen. You can select which event you want as the trigger for the code to be run.

Comment: Btw. instead of clearing the combobox, you could put the text to "". What i mean is, instead of `Sheets.("Sheetname").ComboBox1.clear` write `Sheets.("Sheetname").ComboBox1.Text = ""`

Comment: I know it's simple, but...You are a genius :D Thanks :)